# OVH VPS - firewalld not working in Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, vps, firewalld, ovh

I installed a new server on OVH with CentOS 7:

```
yum install firewalld
```

then enabled and rebooted

```
systemctl enable firewalld   
reboot
```

I am now be able to login using ssh but firewalld does not come up

```
[root@~]# firewall-cmd --state
failed

[root@~]# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
<empty line>
[root@~]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
<empty line>
[root@~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-05 16:49:13 CET; 7min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 1989 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─1989 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Dec 05 16:49:13 systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Dec 05 16:49:13 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Dec 05 16:49:14 firewalld[1989]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                           Error occurred at line: 11...
Dec 05 16:49:14 firewalld[1989]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.4.21: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                           Error occurred at line: 11...
Dec 05 16:49:14 firewalld[1989]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                           Error occurred at line: 10...
Dec 05 16:49:14 firewalld[1989]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.4.21: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                           Error occurred at line: 10...
Dec 05 16:49:14 firewalld[1989]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.4.21: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                           Error occurred at line: 10...
Dec 05 16:49:27 firewalld[1989]: ERROR: INVALID_ZONE
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

If i try the following I still get errors:

```
[root@/]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --change-interface=eth0
Error: 'filter'
```

How can I solve this???

Comment: The OVH customised Centos kernel is missing the required packages to allow firewalld to run correctly. This occurs on their Centos dedicated systems and VPS. They are of the opinion there is no problem. Your options are to change the kernel or change the whole OS image.